# Sed Out of a Pair of Words

Tags: regex, sed

One can use a command such as the following to substitute the word "before" to the word "after" where "before" occurs between the pair of words "begin" and "end":

> sed '/begin/,/end/ {s/before/after/g}'

I am looking for a way to substitute "before" by "after" only if they do **not** occur inside a pair of "begin" and "end".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inversion is almost trivial:

```
sed '/begin/,/end/ !s/before/after/g'
```

Be aware that given the following input

```
begin before end
before
end
before
begin
before end
before
end
before
```

Your original script gives the output:

```
begin after end
after
end
before
begin
after end
before
end
before
```

Note that the 'end' on the same line as the 'begin' does not turn off the substitution.  (And if you use 'end before' after a 'begin', the 'before' is still substituted by 'after'.)

Comment: There is a superflous 's' at the start of the address range.

Answer (score 0):

The right tool for that job is `awk` rather than `sed`. To do the same thing as your current `sed`:

```
echo 'before
begin
before
end
before' | awk '
    BEGIN {st=0;}
    /begin/ {st=1;}
    /end/ {st=0;}
    {
        if (st==1) {
            gsub("before","after");
            print;
        } else {
            print
        }
    }'
```

will give you:

```
before
begin
after
end
before
```

If you reverse the sense of the `if` statement controlling the `gsub`, you will get what you want:

```
echo 'before
begin
before
end
before' | awk '
    BEGIN {st=0;}
    /begin/ {st=1;}
    /end/ {st=0;}
    {
        if (st==0) {
            gsub("before","after");
            print;
        } else {
            print
        }
    }'
```

will give you:

```
after
begin
before
end
after
```

Comment: -1 because the sed version is completely trivial, and more appropriate than awk

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/begin/{f=1}/end/{f=0}!f{ gsub("before","after")}1' file
```